# 2 Product lines sharing same code

Tags: c#, oop, refactoring, factory

We are working on two product lines that will share the same code.

For functionality that differs, I have both product lines implement the same interface (or base classes in some case) and these types will be created in the Main class (which is separate for both product lines) and passed further downstream.

For code that is deep inside the business logic, it is very hard to have product line specific code. We do not want to user if(ProductLine == "ProductLine1") and else methodology.

So I am planning to implement a Factory class which will have static methods to return NewObject1(), NewObject2() and so on. This Factory class will be registered in the Main class as Factory.RegisterClient(ProductLine1).

So with the above approach, the factory(which internally contains ProductLine1Factor & ProductLine2Factory) knows which type of objects to create.

Do you know a better approach to this problem. Please note that ProductLine1 was already existing and ProductLine2 is something new (but is 90% similar to ProductLine1). We cannot do drastic refactoring such that both product lines exist. We want to do as minimally invasive code changes as possible.

The factory approach typically exposes an interface, but the problem with interfaces is that I cannot expose static types which are also needed.

I would really appreciate if some experts would shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach sounds fine.

Instead of a custom crafted factory, why don't you use a fully fledged IoC framework like NInject or Unity? You could have the service implemented twice, for each client, and select one in a container configuration file, statically. This way you don't even need to change the single line of your code if you add yet another implementation, you just reconfigure i.e. make some changes in the xml file.

Anyway, an IoC container is just a tool, use it or not, it just replaces your factory (IoC containers are sometimes called "factories on steroids").